# Missing basic DOM types in TypeScript project

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I am setting a web app up in TypeScript and I seem to be missing some basic types I need.

When I compile (`npm run build`), I get the following errors,

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.
>
> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SVGElement'.
>
> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'EventTarget'.
>
> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'TouchEvent'.
>
> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MouseEvent'.
>
> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PointerEvent'.

Based on my Googling I assuming I am missing something basic in my project setup. It seems like these types are just assumed to be there with Typescript.

EDIT: Specially it should be part of the ES6 types, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts.

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "wip",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "3.4.35",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.39",
    "@types/node": "7.0.5",
    "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.34",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "mocha": "3.2.0",
    "safe-mock": "0.2.0",
    "ts-node": "2.1.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.1",
    "typescript": "2.2.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha test --require ts-node/register test/**/*.ts && npm run build",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --watch --content-base . -d --progress",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `npm run-script build` have you tried this command?

Comment: @Smit, yes, that is the command the leads to the compilation time type errors

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Try adding the following `lib` section to your `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es2016",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix it, thanks! Though I use `es6` instead of `es2016`. Strange that I needed to do that because I had the type in my `node_modules` directory.

Comment: This is the correct solution, currently, but beware of this. Your build will not fail if you use a variable 'event' that is not defined in that file, because lib.dom.d.ts is declaring 'event' as well as a number of other very common variable names.

Comment: [It didn't work for me, sadly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74035705/4756173) :/

Comment: this doesn't work on an nx workspace

Comment: Out of the blue, in a project that never gave me any grief before, I'm getting an error that `document` isn't defined. My compiler options, which are as above, haven't changed.

Answer (score 2):

*Additional answer for testing.*

If using mocha, you also need to tell mocha about the DOM environment using `jsdom`.

https://journal.artfuldev.com/unit-testing-node-applications-with-typescript-using-mocha-and-chai-384ef05f32b2

```
$ npm install jsdom jsdom-global --save-dev
```

So your "test" script would add `-r jsdom-global/register`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha test -r ts-node/register -r jsdom-global/register test/**/*.ts && npm run build"
  }
}
```