# TS2304:Cannot find name 'btoa'

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I'm using `btoa` method for hashing username, password which seems to work fine but this error shows up in my TypeScript errors - WebStorm. How to resolve this?

**js code**

```
let base64hash = btoa(user.username+ ':' + user.key);
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
/* tsconfig.json */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: We can start with you posting relevant code and configuration.

Comment: Related: [Missing basic DOM types in TypeScript project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603783/missing-basic-dom-types-in-typescript-project?rq=1)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason that the compiler can't find the definition for `btoa()` is that you're not including all the necessary libs.

When you use the `--lib` compiler option you need to include all the libs that are included by default when you're not using this option.
In your case what's missing is the `DOM` lib, so it should be:

```
/* tsconfig.json */
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "lib": [
            "es2016", "DOM"
        ]
    }
}
```

As the definition for [btoa is in the lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L13783).

Comment: Setting `"lib": ["es2016", "DOM"]` still leads to "btoa is not defined" when I run tests. Does the `lib.dom.d.ts` need to be referenced or are their other `tsconfig.json` options that are needed?