# ReferenceError: Node is not defined (trying to use Node interface in typescript function in nodejs application)

Tags: node.js, typescript, dom

While extending Cheerio library, I implemented the following static function (other extension functions work fine):

```
$.nodeType = function (elem: CheerioElement): number {
    switch (elem.type) {
        case "comment":
            return Node.COMMENT_NODE; // <--- it fails here
        case "tag":
            return Node.ELEMENT_NODE; // <--- it fails here
        case "text":
            return Node.TEXT_NODE;    // <--- it fails here
        default:
            return -1;
    }
};
```

The following error appears during runtime (compilation with `tsc -b` succeed):

> ReferenceError: Node is not defined

`Node` interface is part of the `DOM` API. Thus, I [realized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603783/missing-basic-dom-types-in-typescript-project) the need of explicitly include the `DOM` API under `compilerOptions` section of `tsconfig.json`.

However, I still get that runtime error.

Minimal relevant part of `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "incremental": true,
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "dom"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "outDir": "./lib/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "esnext",
        "watch": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts",
    ]
}
```

I thought of explicitly import `Node` lib in the specific `.ts` file which contains the function, but I didn't find any "include-able" standard `DOM` lib.

Comment: You cannot use interfaces as values. They're types. Types don't exist at runtime.

Comment: Thanks @estus, i understood. It's the answer so post it as one...

Comment: I'm not sure that it's a good answer since it doesn't explain how it should be fixed. I cannot say how this should be fixed without seeing the context but it's likely can be fixed with JSDOM, as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Including a typescript lib doesn't polyfill the feature in an environment where it is not available.

While including "dom" type definitions will make the types available (at the compile time), but it doesn't actually make the [Node API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) (typically provided by the browser runtime) available at runtime.

If you really need this functionality at runtime, you will need to also include an implementation of DOM for node.js such as [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) which [provides](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/628d1f5/lib/jsdom/living/node-type.js) this API.

Answer (score 1):

[lorefnon explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55678867/399105)  the problem; here's a slightly hacky way to fix it:

1. Install jsdom

   ```
   npm install jsdom
   ```
2. Add this to the top of your file:

   ```js
   const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom'); // or import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
   const Node = new JSDOM('').window.Node;
   ```