# Mock WebAPI interface using ts-mockito

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, webapi, ts-mockito

I'm writing a unit test for a class which uses [browser WebAPI interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API#Interfaces).
I use ts-mockito to mock the interface (a [WebGL2RenderingContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL2RenderingContext) in my case).

When I run the test, Node throws `ReferenceError: WebGL2RenderingContext is not defined`
which is understandable, because the test is run under NodeJS environment, not browser, so the class/interface doesn't exist.

Is there any way to make NodeJS environment aware of the WebAPI interfaces, so that it's possible to be mocked?

**NOTE**: Since it's a unit test, it should *NOT* be run on a real browser.
[jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) seems to be a possible solution, but I have no idea how to mock it with ts-mockito.

---

The following snippet illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```typescript
import { mock, instance, verify } from 'ts-mockito'

// ========== CLASS ==========
class DummyClass {
    dummyMethod() : void {}
}

class TestedClass {
    static testDummy(dummy : DummyClass) : void {
        dummy.dummyMethod();
    }

    static testGlCtx(glCtx : WebGL2RenderingContext) : void {
        glCtx.flush();
    }
}

// ========== TEST ==========
describe('DummyClass', () => {
    // This test passed successfully
    it('works fine', () => {
        const mockDummy = mock(DummyClass);

        TestedClass.testDummy( instance(mockDummy) );

        verify( mockDummy.dummyMethod() ).once();
    });
});

describe('WebGL interface', () => {
    it('works fine', () => {
        // This line failed with 'ReferenceError: WebGL2RenderingContext is not defined'
        const mockGLCtx = mock(WebGL2RenderingContext);

        TestedClass.testGlCtx( instance(mockGLCtx) );

        verify( mockGLCtx.flush() ).once();
    });
});
```

Run using mocha with the command `mocha --require ts-node/register 'test.ts'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions: For common DOM APIs, and for generic mocking.

### For common DOM APIs

As detailed in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603783/missing-basic-dom-types-in-typescript-project#answer-59690287), jsdom can be used to bring DOM APIs into NodeJS runtime environment.

Run `npm install --save-dev jsdom global-jsdom`
and change Mocha's command to

```
mocha --require ts-node/register --require global-jsdom/register 'test.ts'
```

*NOTE*: [global-jsdom](https://github.com/modosc/global-jsdom) is the newer & updated version of [jsdom-global](https://github.com/rstacruz/jsdom-global).

This solution works for common DOM APIs (such as `HTMLElement`, `SVGElement`, `File`),
but it doesn't work for more specialized APIs (WebGL, Crypto, audio & video).

### For generic interface mocking

Turns out ts-mockito [has a way to mock interfaces](https://github.com/NagRock/ts-mockito#mocking-interfaces), including DOM & any browser Web APIs.

So the above test code can be changed to:

```typescript
describe('WebGL interface', () => {
    it('works fine', () => {
        const mockGLCtx = mock<WebGL2RenderingContext>();

        TestedClass.testGlCtx( instance(mockGLCtx) );

        verify( mockGLCtx.flush() ).once();
    });
});
```

and the test will run successfully.